# D3js SVG Overlap: Custom Colors with Many SVGs of random shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I need to accomplish the color "blending" shown in the image -- for areas where there are 2 shapes overlapping it needs to display as a particular color (orange here), and a separate color for 3 overlap (red here).

I need something very dynamic and easy to extend to more overlapping shapes. There may be up to 20 shapes that overlap in various areas. Shapes are random, with no predictable form.

I am drawing the shapes as SVG polygons using D3js.

I have tried the css *mix-blend-mode* but it is not useful for my needs. I have been researching this for two days with no luck...

[image]

Comment: In what form is the data used to draw the polygons?

Comment: pixel coordinates that i just append to <polygon> for example: <polygon points="849,412 849,422 842,420

Comment: Why is mix-blend-mode unsuitable?

Answer (score 2):

if `mix-blend-mode` is not useful for your needs ( maybe you don't like the colors or you didn't applied `isolation: isolate;` to the group ) you may try using `clipPath`.

Since you don't publish your code I can't work on your example. The code that comes next may give you some ideas.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:lang="en"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
height="360px" width="360px" viewBox="-18 -12.5 36 36">
<title>Venn Diagram</title>
<style>
.left { fill: #1dd0b8; }
.right { fill: #47ef96; }
.circle{ fill: #b147ef; }
.outlines {
fill: none;
stroke: black;
}
</style>
<defs>
<circle id="c" r="11.5" />
<use id="left" xlink:href="#c" x="-6"/>
<use id="right" xlink:href="#c" x="6"/>
<use id="circle" xlink:href="#c" y="10"/> 

<clipPath id="clip-left">
  <use xlink:href="#c" x="-6" />
</clipPath>
  
<clipPath id="clip-right">
  <use xlink:href="#c" x="+6" />
</clipPath> 
  
<clipPath id="clip-both" clip-path="url(#clip-left)">
<defs>a clipPath element can have a clip-path
applied to it.</defs>
<use xlink:href="#c" x="6" />
</clipPath> 
</defs>
  
<use xlink:href="#left" class="left" />
<use xlink:href="#right" class="right" />
<use xlink:href="#circle" class="circle" />

<g clip-path="url(#clip-left)">
<use xlink:href="#c" x="+6" fill="#e89f0c" />
</g>
<g clip-path="url(#clip-right)">
<use xlink:href="#c" x="0" y="10" fill="#e89f0c" />
</g> 
<g clip-path="url(#clip-left)">
<use xlink:href="#c" y="10" fill="yellow" />
</g> 
  
<g clip-path="url(#clip-both)">
<use xlink:href="#c" y="10" fill="red" />
</g>
  
    
<g class="outlines">
<use xlink:href="#left" />
<use xlink:href="#right" />
<use xlink:href="#circle" />
</g>
</svg>
```

The example above is heavily inspired by "clipping a clipPath" from [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HZ31YZ)