# d3 count overlapping shapes at point

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I have this basic drawing of ellipses: https://codepen.io/almn22/pen/zJrWrd

I am trying to make it so that when you mouse over an area, there is text output below that displays how many shapes are at that point. So in the example below, when you mouseover the darkest gray area, there should be a text display of "3".

For my real use case, the shapes are random with no predictable form so I can't count on them being ellipses or circles. I am plotting them as svg polygons using d3js. The data I have for the polygons is just the "points" attribute.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }
    ellipse {
  stroke: white;
  fill: lightgray;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    const svgContainer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width","560")
    .attr("height","900").attr("translate", "45, 45");

    const ellipses = [
    {"cx":  145, "cy":  125, "rx": 88, "ry": 20},
    {"cx":  175, "cy":  175, "rx": 88, "ry": 77},
    {"cx": 225, "cy": 125, "rx": 88, "ry": 55},
    {"cx": 275, "cy": 275, "rx": 88, "ry": 77}
  ];

    const svgEllipses = svgContainer
    .selectAll("ellipse")
    .data(ellipses)
    .enter()
    .append("ellipse");

    svgEllipses
     .attr("cx", (d,i) => { return d.cx; })
     .attr("cy", (d,i) => { return d.cy; })
     .attr("rx", (d,i) => { return d.rx; })
     .attr("ry", (d,i) => { return d.ry; });
    

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012949/d3js-svg-overlap-custom-colors-with-many-svgs-of-random-shape only phrased a bit different.

Comment: rio it absolutely is not. if you have an easy solution, please provide

Comment: get the mouse position and do a point-in-polygon test over all your shapes. But as soon as you allow rotated-translated-skewed shapes you have a bit more math to do.

Comment: Thanks! Would you know how I can determine which shape is "on top" at a given point?

Comment: if you traverse the list of shapes the last shape that has a point-in-polygon

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to this question.

The main idea is that on click all the shapes are insensitive to the mouse. Also a counter `n` is started from 0. Then one by one every shape become sensitive to the mouse. If the mouse is inside the shape the counter `n` is is increasing by one: `n++`.

I hope it helps.

```js
let m = {};// mouse
let shapes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".shape"));

svg.addEventListener("click", e => {  
  let n = 0;// a counter
  m = oMousePos(e);// thr mouse position on click
  shapes.map(s=>{
  // all the shapes are insensitive to the mouse
  shapes.map(_s=>{_s.style.pointerEvents = "none";})
  // this shape is the only one sensitive to the mouse in this moment
  s.style.pointerEvents = "all";
  // detecting if the mouse is inside the shape
  let elmt = document.elementFromPoint(m.x, m.y);
  // if it is and the element has className.baseVal == "shape"
  if(elmt.className.baseVal == "shape"){
    //increase tho counter
    n++
  };
});
  //use the counter
  console.log(n);
});

function oMousePos(evt) {
  return {
    x: evt.clientX,
    y: evt.clientY
  };
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shape {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="400" translate="45, 45">
  <ellipse class="shape" cx="145" cy="125" rx="88" ry="20" fill="#aaa"></ellipse>
  <circle class="shape" cx="175" cy="175" r="88" fill="#bbb"></circle>
  <ellipse class="shape" cx="225" cy="125" rx="88" ry="55" fill="#ccc"></ellipse>
  <circle class="shape" cx="275" cy="275" r="77" fill="#ddd"></circle>
</svg>
```